# Teradata - Cannot nest aggregate operations min(avg)

Tags: sql, teradata

I want to get the month a store had its lowest average revenue. I either get a list of  all the stores (the code below is giving me all 12 months for a store) or when i try min(avg_rev) in the inner select it says 'Teradata - Cannot nest aggregate operations'. Please help.

```
| store | yearmonth | min(avg_rev)|
| 102   | 2004 9    | $2000       |
| 103   | 2004 8    | $30000      |
etc
```

```
SELECT STORE, month_num||year_num AS yearmonth, min(avg_rev)
FROM (SELECT store, EXTRACT(year from saledate) AS year_num, 
   EXTRACT(month from saledate) AS month_num,
   sum(amt)/ COUNT (distinct saledate) AS avg_rev
   FROM trnsact
   WHERE stype='p'
   GROUP BY year_num, month_num,store
   HAVING NOT(year_num=2005 AND month_num=8) AND COUNT (distinct saledate)>20) AS clean_data

GROUP BY store, yearmonth, avg_rev
ORDER BY store asc, min(avg_rev)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use `qualify` to choose the month:

```
SELECT store, EXTRACT(year from saledate) AS year_num, 
       EXTRACT(month from saledate) AS month_num,
       sum(amt)/ COUNT(distinct saledate) AS avg_rev
FROM trnsact
WHERE stype='p'
GROUP BY year_num, month_num, store
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY store ORDER BY avg_rev ASC) = 1
```